# 95% confidence interval for AUROCC?

Tags: confidence-interval

How do I calculate the 95% confidence interval of the area under the ROC curve (AUROCC) on BlueSky Statistics? I know how to create the multivariate logistic model and show the ROC curve and AUROCC. I tried using the Bootstrap Resampling but could not figure out how to get the 95% confidence interval.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with R, you may want to enter the corresponding R codes to perform the calculation you are looking for (see chapter 4 of the user manual for V10 for further details on using R code with BlueSky)

For example, I was able to use some R code to directly connect to MySQL as well as to open a SQLite database file.